# Google map api play framework location marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have problem with putting marker on map. I have model Location where i save coordinates x and y. I read from base all coordinates in list and send that list in view. Than I tried to go trought all list and put markers on loc. But it doesnt work. Here is my code.

```
@(places: java.util.List[models.Location])
@adminmain("Post Offices") {

<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="@routes.Application.adminPanel()">Admin Panel</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Maps</a></li>
    <li class="active">Location</li>
</ol>
<h1>Maps</h1
<div class="templatemo-maps">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 margin-bottom-30">
            <div id="map" style="position: relative; height: 700px; width: auto"></div>
```

AND SCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
               var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),           {
 zoom: 5,
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.8331, 18.3039),
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP});


   var i;
     for(i = 0; i<@places.size(); i++){
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(@places.get(i).x,@places.get(i).y),
    map: map
  });
}
map.addListener('center_changed', function() {
// 3 seconds after the center of the map has changed, pan back to the marker
window.setTimeout(function() {
  map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
}, 3000);});
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
});
```

Comment: Are the map and data in same coordinate system? I mean there are so many possibilities what the x and y can mean and if they refer to different coordinate systems the point can appear to other side of the globe. X and Y are counts from some origo but really your coordinates have to share same origo and map boundaries.

Comment: Thats ok. When I say in code this:
position: new google.maps.LatLng(@places.get(0).x,@places.get(0).y),

it works but when I put i in places.get(i).x it doesnt work.

Comment: Because i type is var and function places.get() accept type int. And I got error i is not valid

Answer (score 0):

If anyone have problem with this I found solution. U must write for each statement from scala lang. Like this:

```
@for(place <- places) {

 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(@place.x
                , @place.y),
    map: map
    });
    }
```

And it works!